# Obtaining standard errors for Nelson Siegel coefficients

Tags: r

I am using the package `YieldCurve` to obtain Nelson Siegel parameters.

The standard example:

```
library("YieldCurve")
data(FedYieldCurve)

maturity.Fed <- c(3/12, 0.5, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 10)

NSParameters <- Nelson.Siegel(rate=first(FedYieldCurve, '10 month'), 
                              maturity=maturity.Fed)
```

How do I obtain the standard errors of the parameters, for example `beta_0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could bootstrap the standard errors. According to a relevant [post on Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25706/how-do-you-do-bootstrapping-with-time-series-data) the appropriate method for time series is the *block bootstrap*.

One possibility is to use `boot::tsboot` but there might be better approaches (i.e. to apply overlaps, or account for stationarity).

Subset the time series beforehand.

```
tt <- first(FedYieldCurve, '10 month')
```

This is what you've got so far:

```
Nelson.Siegel(rate=first(FedYieldCurve, '10 month'), 
              maturity=maturity.Fed)$beta_0
#              beta_0
# 1982-01-01 14.34594
# 1982-02-01 14.14681
# 1982-03-01 13.61065
# 1982-04-01 13.61517
# 1982-05-01 13.52630
# 1982-06-01 14.13378
# 1982-07-01 13.84696
# 1982-08-01 13.02162
# 1982-09-01 12.10749
# 1982-10-01 11.02616
```

And here the bootstrap:

```
library(boot)
FUN <- function(tt) Nelson.Siegel(rate=tt, maturity=maturity.Fed)$beta_0
set.seed(42)
res <- tsboot(tt, FUN, R=999, l=4, sim="fixed")
res
# BLOCK BOOTSTRAP FOR TIME SERIES
# 
# Fixed Block Length of 4 
# 
# Call:
#   tsboot(tseries = tt, statistic = FUN, R = 999, l = 4, sim = "fixed")
# 
# 
# Bootstrap Statistics :
#            original      bias    std. error
# 1982-01-01 14.34594 -0.13196802   0.2612880
# 1982-02-01 14.14681 -0.11939397   0.2973519
# 1982-03-01 13.61065  0.21889530   0.2847908
# 1982-04-01 13.61517  0.13024656   0.2722655
# 1982-05-01 13.52630  0.14400794   0.3407014
# 1982-06-01 14.13378 -0.53877853   0.4418189
# 1982-07-01 13.84696 -0.45311547   0.6637142
# 1982-08-01 13.02162  0.03079636   0.8099144
# 1982-09-01 12.10749  0.25592742   1.0325852
# 1982-10-01 11.02616  0.54346793   0.9569845
```

*Note:* If you don't want this code to run forever, you may decrease the replications to e.g. `R=99` for testing.

You probably need to study the block bootstrap in more detail following the information given in the two answers of the linked Cross Validated post. I  couldn't tell you what the correct block length (the `l=` parameter) was, for example.

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much! I had to make a minor adjustment, because it didn't like $beta_0 (atomic vector problems). The bootstrapping works fine date by date.  

`library(boot)
FUN <- function(tt) Nelson.Siegel(rate=tt, maturity=maturity.Fed)
set.seed(42)
res <- tsboot(tt, FUN, R=999, l=4, sim="fixed")
res`